# Sending current timestamp in postman request body

Tags: timestamp, postman

I used `{{$timestamp}}` command in my postman script to send the current timestamp but it displays the time on my app UI as Jan 19, 1970, 12:16:20 AM which was not the current timestamp. The request was sent on Nov 19th at 11:20 a.m. Is something else required to be done here in this case?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows your problem?

Comment: Are you able to provide more context please, if possible, an example of what you're seeing in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You could use moment.js library with Postman to give you that timestamp format.
You can add this to the pre-request script in postman and format your date with appropriate date format:

```
const moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("timestamp", moment().format("MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a"));
```

Then you can use `{{timestamp}}` anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using {{$timestamp}}, change it to {{timestamp}} instead. $ makes a diff.